# Find working days between two dates in a specific format

Tags: mysql, date

Here is a problem. I need to find working days between two dates (without weekends). I currently found and was able to successfully use this approach:

```
SELECT 5 * (DATEDIFF(DateClosed, DateOpened) DIV 7) + MID('0123455501234445012333450122234501101234000123450', 
  7 * WEEKDAY(DateOpened) + WEEKDAY(DateClosed) + 1, 1) AS TotalResolutionTimeBusinessDays 
FROM table1
```

This is a complex calculation based on a matrix:

```
 | M T W T F S S
-|--------------
M| 0 1 2 3 4 5 5
T| 5 0 1 2 3 4 4
W| 4 5 0 1 2 3 3
T| 3 4 5 0 1 2 2
F| 2 3 4 5 0 1 1
S| 0 1 2 3 4 0 0
S| 0 1 2 3 4 5 0
```

In the matrix, the intersection of any given x and y value pair (WEEKDAY(@S) and WEEKDAY(@E) yields the difference in work days between the two values. The 49 values in the table are concatenated into the following string: `0123455501234445012333450122234501101234000123450`.

This works fine for me but now I need to present difference between dates in another format. E.g.: Let's say we have two dates: StartDate = '2013-06-28 01:27:35' and EndDate = '2013-07-08 16:47:21'. If we use method described above we get 7 working days which is correct. But I need to count all the difference between dates(including hours and minutes) so it could look like

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2013-07-08 16:47:21','2013-06-28 01:27:35')) / 3600 / 24
```

which without weekends should be value like 7.64 days.

Any suggestions how to write a calculation based on that format? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use your current approach to get the full days and then subtract the time from the start and the end.

Comment: Couldn't understand how does your table look and what are you trying to do with this data.

Comment: @Vatev: could you please describe a function you would use to subtract the time from end and start date?

Comment: Surely to determine "working days", one needs to consider locale?  Not just for public holidays, which you don't appear to have considered at all, but also for those countries that have a different "weekend" (e.g. Friday-Saturday in many middle-Eastern countries, but other variations exist).  Please clarify exactly what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: This is a complex problem that is better solved in application libraries. I use Date::Manip in Perl, which handles it nicely: http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.41/lib/Date/Manip/Calc.pod . If you absolutely must do it in MySQL, you might be better off using a UDF to do it, but I'd suggest doing it in your app.